# html if else statement

Tags: html, asp.net

i have 2 buttons in 1 gridview column

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkBlue" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Width="5px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    if<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "stat")%>=="S2"
                    {
                    <a href="QP_OJT.aspx?Emp_id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EMP_ID")%>&Train_B_N=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Train_B_N")%>&Train_ID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Train_ID")%>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">QP-003/05/02</a>
                    }else
                    {
                    <a href="QP_Eval.aspx?Train_ID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Train_ID")%>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">QP-003/09/03</a>
                    }
                </ItemTemplate>
```

if stat = "s2",QP-003/05/02 visible = true,else QP-003/05/02 is visible is false.
please guide me on this,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using and HTML `<a>` element you could use and ASP.NET `LinkButton` control.When the HTML get's generated it also get's translated to an `<a>` element but on a `LinkButton` control you have a `Visible` property which can be controlled programatically to show\hide the link - `Visible='<%# Eval("stat") == "S2" %>'`

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("EMP_ID") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("Train_ID") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ojt" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/QP_OJT.aspx?Emp_id=" + Eval("EMP_ID") %>' runat="server" Text="QP-003/05/02" Visible='<%# Eval("stat") == "S2" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="eval" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/QP_Eval.aspx?Train_ID=" + Eval("Train_ID") %>' runat="server" Text="QP-003/09/03" Visible='<%# Eval("stat") != "S2" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public class GvData
{
    public string stat { get; set; }
    public int EMP_ID { get; set; }
    public int Train_ID { get; set; }

}

public partial class GridViewConditionalButtons : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var g1 = new GvData { stat = "S2", Train_ID = 1, EMP_ID = 1 };
            var g2 = new GvData { stat = "S2", Train_ID = 2, EMP_ID = 2 };
            var g3 = new GvData { stat = "S1", Train_ID = 3, EMP_ID = 3 };

            GridView1.DataSource = new List<GvData> { g1, g2, g3 };
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi denis ,thx for your answer,but i would prefer answer in html.

Comment: LinkButton gets translated to <a> anyway.There's no reason not to use it.If you really want to you can use jQuery to loop through the GrdiView and set the visibility using javascript.There are a ton of articles on the internet showing you how to do this